# How to fix "AddDefaultTypes should be called before creating a Realm instance with the default schema."

Tags: android, xamarin, realm

When I try to open an application after a notification from Firebase Cloud Messages, the application closes with the following error:

```
07-09 12:24:22.404          Samsung SM-A510F       Info       15570    MonoDroid        System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. ---> System.NotSupportedException: AddDefaultTypes should be called before creating a Realm instance with the default schema. If you see this error, please report it to help@realm.io.
at Realms.Schema.RealmSchema.AddDefaultTypes (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] types) [0x00029] in <62b40c9633874f2cb89599c718233d7b>:0
  at RealmModuleInitializer.Initialize () [0x00000] in <24d2a06b332042f2a7af7631479a79db>:0
  at <Module>..cctor () [0x00000] in <24d2a06b332042f2a7af7631479a79db>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Autofac.Module.Configure (Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistry componentRegistry) [0x0001a] in <57e4c9c21cbb498aacce99da9e049074>:0
  at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build (Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, System.Boolean excludeDefaultModules) [0x0004b] in <57e4c9c21cbb498aacce99da9e049074>:0
  at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build (Autofac.Builder.ContainerBuildOptions options) [0x0002e] in <57e4c9c21cbb498aacce99da9e049074>:0
  at Retail360.Kernel.Build () [0x00071] in <3e794d04561a416fae55be827fe69b19>:0
  at Retail360.App..ctor () [0x00015] in <3e794d04561a416fae55be827fe69b19>:0
  at Retail360.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x0003d] in <9722cafe2466481e865733de664af995>:0
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <2530aa2e412d4754af3ae7e1a8c80b6d>:0
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.12(intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

Firebase message sending from background Worker (using AndroidX.Work)
This does not always happen, but I cannot find a pattern. 
I don't register an instance of Realm in Autofac and other registered classes didn't contain  instantiating Realm instanse in constructors.

What does this error mean and what am I doing wrong?

Environment:

- Phone Samsung A5 Android 7.0 or OnePlus 6T Android 9.
- Xamarin Forms 3.6.0.539721
- Realm 4.0.1
- Autofac 4.9.2
- Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.1

Comment: This error log show how to solve it . `AddDefaultTypes should be called before creating a Realm instance with the default schema.`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the error by adding database initialization in MainActivity before creating the job and worker.